# How to get count of array of type at once?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

For example, I have a collection like this:

```
{"_id": 1, "type": 'A', "data": "asdff"},
{"_id": 2, "type": 'B', "data": "fsdfs"},
{"_id": 3, "type": 'A', "data": "aesdf"},
{"_id": 4, "type": 'C', "data": "sdsdd"},
```

I can get type A's count:

```
db.colA.find({type: 'A'}).count()
```

How can  I  get an array of type, for example, A, B, C 's count

```
db.colA.find({type: {$in: ['A', 'B', 'C']}}).countByType() ??
```

Should I do a loop like `db.colA.find({type: type}).count()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this, you need to use the aggregation framework. You simply need to [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) your documents by "type" and use the [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) accumulator operator to return the "count" for each "type".

```
db.colA.aggregate(
    [ 
        { "$match": { "type": { "$in": [ "A", "B", "C" ] } },
        { "$group": { 
            "_id": "$type", 
            "count": { "$sum": 1 } 
        }}
    ]
)
```

Of course you can always get the total count for "A", "B", "C" using the [`count()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/) method:

```
db.colA.count( { "type": { "$in": [ "A", "B", "C" ] } } )
```

Answer (score 1):

This Works For Me:

```
db.getCollection('Mytest').aggregate([{
           $group:
             {_id: {"type":"$type"},"count": { $sum: 1 }}}])
```

Output:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "type" : "C"
    },
    "count" : 1
}


{
    "_id" : {
        "type" : "B"
    },
    "count" : 1
}


{
    "_id" : {
        "type" : "A"
    },
    "count" : 2
}
```